# Need to display a clickable image on top of another image

Tags: jquery, html

I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7NXf/) of what I am trying to do. When I hover over the main image, I want a trash can image to show up. This part works. My issue is that when I hover over the trash can image, it like flashes and disappears as I move the mouse over it.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
    <div style="position: relative; left:0;top:0">
        <img id="test1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; position: relative; top:0; left:0" />
        <img id="test1trash" src="http://www.nonamescriptware.com/wp-content/uploads/trashcan.png" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; position: absolute; top: 28px; left: 32px; cursor: pointer; display: none" />
</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#imagesContainer img:not([id$=trash])").hover(function () {
        $(this).next('#imagesContainer img[id$=trash]').show();
    }, function () {                   
        $('#imagesContainer img[id$=trash]').hide();
    });
});
```

I think I can grasp what is happening. I think when I hover over the trash can, the main image receives a mouse out event, which hides the trash can. Then when the mouse moves, since the trash can is gone, the main image receives the mouse in event, which then shows the trash can.

My question is how can I fix this?

Comment: did you try using mousenter and mouseleave events instead of hover, I seem to remember this issue myself and have a vague memory of this being a solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u7NXf/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this CSS solution does the trick for you

http://jsfiddle.net/u7NXf/4/

```
#test1:hover + #test1trash, #test1trash:hover{
    display: block;    
}
#test1trash{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 for CSS only. And in the event, there are more than one `div` inside `#imagesContainer`, you can update the code to [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/sAVTn/)

Comment: I like this solution. The only problem is my images are dynamically placed, so I won't know the ID names in advance to do the CSS styling.

Comment: You should check out the fiddle in the comment from @kei, his/her solution uses classes instead id's.  That would allow you to use dynamic images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean solution - http://jsfiddle.net/u7NXf/5/

```
 $(function() {
    $("#imagesContainer img").mouseenter(function () {
                    $(this).next('#imagesContainer img[id$=trash]').show();
                });
    $("#imagesContainer").mouseleave(function (){                   
                    $('#imagesContainer img[id$=trash]').hide();
                });

});
```

Comment: This seems to work nice except when I slide my mouse off the image, to the right, the trash can image is still there. If I move my mouse down though, it seems to work.

Comment: It is because #imageContainer is the full width of the browser. If you change the container to be the width of the image the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the event handler on the `div` around the two `img` as I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/u7NXf/2/

The hover event will bubble from the inner elements (the `img`) to the outer element (the `div`). Therefore the hover event will fire, even when the trashcan is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use JS for this, here try this CSS solution:

CSS (delete the inline display style from #test1trash):

```
#test1trash {display:none;}

#imagesContainer:hover #test1trash { display:block;}
```

Comment: Nice, except the images are dynamically placed there, so I won't know the IDs in advance.

Comment: Even with it being dynamically placed, you should be able to set a class or id from your template code.